# Exponential function to map from [0, 1] to arbitrary [min, max]?

Tags: calculus

Maybe you can help out a programmer whose last math class was 20 years ago:

Given a base $b$, $y_{min}$ and $y_{max}$:

Define a function so that $f(0) = y_{min}$, $f(1) = y_{max}$ and f(x) is exponential in [0, 1] using the given base.
Define the inverse function.

### Trivial example

$y_{min} = 1$, $y_{max} = 16$, $b = 2$

$$y = 2 ^ 4x$$

$$x = log_2(y) / 4$$

### For positive values of $y_{min}$

I came up with the general form:

$$y = 2^{ x (log_b(y_{max}) - log_b(y_{min})) + log_b(y_{min}) }$$

$$x = \frac{log_b(y) - log_b(y_{min})}{(log_b(y_{max}) - log_b(y_{min})}$$

### Arbitrary ranges?

How to make it work, with arbitrary values, for example $b = 10$, $y_{min} = -1.000$, $y_{max} = 10,000$.

I suspect the question is not even valid for this range, but for my requirement it looks sensible at first sight:

Have a slider (user interface component) whose

- minimum value is -1,000
- maximum value is 10,000
- with equal-distances for -100, -10, 0, 10, 100, 1000
- sensible values in between

[image: slider component]

It also looks simple when you define x = 0 for leftmost slider position, x = 1 for rightmost position and draw the graph with a (pseudo?) logarithmic scale on the y-axis:

[image: graph]

How to best handle that?
A problem, of course is that there is just no $x$ for which $b^x = 0$.

Maybe we need three separate functions: One for $y = [y_{min}, -eps]$, one for $y = [eps, y_{max}]$, and one for $y = ]-eps, eps[$ where we cheat and approximate?

Comment: Is the function supposed to be increasing?  That is, should $f(0) = \min$ and $f(1) = \max$?

Comment: @hardmath Yes, basically it should increase linearly from min to max on a logarithmic scale.

Comment: A logarithmic scale only makes sense if $\min$ and $\max$ are both positive, as Noah's answer points out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a truly logarithmic scale, where your $0$ is there would be $1$, where your $-10$ is there would be $0.1$, where your $-100$ is, there would be $0.01$, and where your $-1000$ is there would be $0.001$.

I guess you would be better served with a $(\sinh x)$-style solution, that is, the difference between two exponentials of opposite sign of the exponent. Close to $0$ that's linear, and then it goes into exponential quite fast. For example, consider $$f(x) = 10^x - 10^{-x}$$
Then you've got $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=9.9\approx 10$, $f(2)=99.99\approx 100$, $f(3)=999.999\approx 1000$, $f(4)=9999.9999\approx 10\,000$, and of course $f(-x)=-f(x)$.

So taking the function $7x-3$ which is $-3$ for $x=0$ and $4$ for $x=1$, the function
$$f(x)=10^{7x-3} - 10^{-(7x-3)}$$
would range from $-999.999$ to $9999.9999$, which I guess is close enough to your desired range of $-1000$ to $10\,000$.

If you need exact values, you can use the reverse function to $f$, which is
$$f^{-1}(y) = \log_{10}\frac{y+\sqrt{y^2+4}}{2}$$
and then use a standard linear scaling to map that to the range $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks! That's a very nice solution. I'll code it and try how it works out in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Exponential functions can't change sign: if $f(x)=ab^x$ ($b$ positive, $a\not=0$) then either $f$ is positive everywhere or $f$ is negative everywhere.

Why? Well, remember that $b^x>0$ for all $x$, since $b$ is positive (and an exponential function with *negative* base doesn't really make sense over an interval unless we're in the complex numbers). So either $a$ is negative, in which case $f$ is always negative, or $a$ is positive, in which case $f$ is always positive.

So we need $y_{min}$ and $y_{max}$ to have the same sign. And your function 
$$y = 2^{ x (log_b(y_{max}) - log_b(y_{min})) + log_b(y_{min}) }$$ does the job in each case.

Comment: Yes, I thought so as well. Maybe I have asked the question in too close a form. Have a look at the slider sketch: How would you calculate a sensible value for a slider position?

Answer (score 1):

For the slider function, you can crop the logarithm and then mirror it:

$$x = \mathop{\rm sgn} y \cdot (\log(|y|) + 1)$$
Where $0$ maps to $0$

This function will map the values $-b^k, \ldots, -b, 0, b, \ldots, b^k$ to the points $-k-1, \ldots, -1, 0, 1, \ldots, k+1$.

You can shift this function around, and play with its base to adjust shape and location.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of something like that, too. However that alone still does not really work when x is close to 0. How would the inverse function look like? Even if only considering x >= 0 $y = e^{x - 1}$ would not work for x < 1